# Comparing answers using Data File Handling in a C++ Quiz program

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm developing a *Quiz program* in *Turbo C++* ( I know it's too old fashioned, but I'm bound to do so ) in which I must use *Data File Handling* process to read the questions from a file, then compare the actual answer with the original one. I'm a beginner in C++ so I'm quite confused on how to do it. After checking the correct answer from the file, the next question should appear. I've written the following code till now:

```
//The Infinite Knowledge Quiz Program
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>

class Quiz
{   char userName[30];
    int score;
public:
    void quizComp();
    void dispScore();
    //  void highScore();
    void about();
    void legal();
    void help();
    void start();
    void bScience();
    void bArts();
    void bEnt();
    void bGeo();
    void bInd();
    void bLang();
    void bSports();
    void iScience();
    void iArts();
    void iEnt();
    void iGeo();
    void iInd();
    void iLang();
    void iSports();
    void eScience();
    void eArts();
    void eEnt();
    void eGeo();
    void eInd();
    void eLang();
    void eSports();
};
```

.... then some UI declarations in `main()` function. then the first function which reads a question from *bScQues.txt* file:

```
void bScience()
{ clrscr();
  char userAns, ch[30];
  cout<<"\n You're interested in 'Sciences'";
  cout<<"\n and you think you're a 'Beginner'";
  cout<<"\n So, let's start...";
  ifstream f1;
  f1.open("bScQues.txt");
  cin.getline(ch, 30);
  cout<<ch;
  f1.close();
  cout<<"\n What should be the correct answer?:";
  cin>>userAns;
  }
```

Please help me by providing how to compare the answer written in *bScAns.txt* file. Like *a*, *b*, *c*, or *d*.

Answer (score 2):

try this friend:

first your `bScAns.txt` will contain the answers without any separator like "bcadba" 
then declare your stream globally and open BScAns when you come in to the function `bScience()`

then while checking users ans with the correct just take one letter from the stream using          `stream.get(character);` and compare and go

the file pointer will be adjusted automatically

```
//the code would be like
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>

ifstream ans;
class Quiz
{   char userName[30];
    int score;
...
void bScience()
{ clrscr();
  ans.open("BScAns.txt");
  char userAns, ch[30];
  cout<<"\n You're interested in 'Sciences'";
  cout<<"\n and you think you're a 'Beginner'";
  cout<<"\n So, let's start...";
  ifstream f1;
  f1.open("bScQues.txt");
  f1.getline(ch, 30);
  cout<<ch;
  f1.close();
  cout<<"\n What should be the correct answer?:";
  cin>>userAns;
  char c;
  ans.get(c);
  if(userAns==c)
  cout<<"correct";
  }
```

happy to be of some help

Comment: I've written the following code: char userAns, ch[50], ans;
  ifstream f2;
  f2.open("bScAns.txt");
  cout<<"\n\n\n\n You're interested in 'Sciences'";
  cout<<"\n and you think you're a 'Beginner'";
  cout<<"\n So, let's start...";
  ifstream f1;
  f1.open("bScQues.txt");
  {cin.getline(ch, 50, '\n');
  cout<<ch<<endl;}
  f1.close();
  cout<<"\n\n What's your answer?:";
  cin>>userAns;
  char c;
  ans.get(c);
  if(ch==c)
  { cout<<"\n\n Correct!";
  }
  else
  { cout<<"\n Sorry, but that's a wrong answer!";}
  }

Comment: But I'm recieving two errors : 1.Structure required on left side of . or * in 'ans.get(c)' and Can't convert char to char* in if(ch==c). Please help!

Comment: its correct only recheck your typing and i made one correction missed that

Comment: in Line 11:You're trying to read the question from cin (standard input), not the stream you opened on line 10.And Line 17: ans is a simple char. It does not have a get method.Should I try to get a char from your f2 stream? Line 18: Line 18: You're trying to compare an array (ch) to a simple char (c).It's not working! Then, When I change cin to f1 it results the same error. Please help

Comment: ifstream f2;
  f2.open("bScAns.txt");
  while (!f2.eof())
  {f2.getline(ch, 50, '\n');
  cout<<ch<<endl;}  This is the correct code and now I wonder if someone knows how to display one question at a time present in 'bScQues.txt' file if there are 10 in total. As I've said before, one question, then answer compare then again second question, then compare...Will a loop help?